# Is there a BiMap implementation with predictable iteration ordering (insertion order)?

Tags: java, guava, bimap

The standard library `LinkedHashSet` is a `HashSet` that provides insertion-order iteration. Is there a version of Guava's [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) that maintains insertion-order iteration on keys and values?  I do need the `BiMap` to be mutable, so `ImmutableBiMap` is not sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: Uhm, what should define the insertion order? I take it the keys should?

Comment: I would accept key ordering, but keys and values are put in together and an exception is thrown if you try to put in an existing value under a different key, so I think there is no practical difference.

Comment: you could just implement guava's bimap interface yourself using two linked hashmaps. Probably not too hard to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only available implementation is `ImmutableBiMap<K,V>`. You can check the implementations [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).
You can use a `LinkedHashMap` and convert it to  with `copyOf(Map<? extends K,? extends V> map)` to make it an `ImmutableBiMap<K,V>`. Will it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help.  I want a BiMap for ease of use, but it needs to be mutable.  If I maintain a different collection type (or types, e.g. two maps) then I don't need a BiMap at all.

Comment: Ok Jake but no Guava solution sorry

Answer (score -2):

You could get the keyset, convert it to an array and then loop over the array like this:

```
Object[] keys = someBiMap.keySet().toArray();
for(Object key : keys) {
    Object entry = someBiMap.get(key);
}
```

This is not a very nice solution but it's the only solution that I have found for this problem

Comment: `keySet` returns a `Set`, so it doesn't guarantee insertion order.  With `HashBiMap` they are almost never in insertion order.